# DBFlow Error in Android.. Error:(8, 39) error: cannot find symbol class Class_Table

Tags: android, dbflow

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I have been using `DBFlow` as the ORM for the SQLite Databases in Android but Somehow I'm not able to run again after the program run once. It says that error:

> cannot find symbol class `Class_table`.

What is the problem and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

Build your project 3-4  times and It will get generated.Also, try changing the database version of your database .I faced the similar issue and this is the only way to make it work.

Comment: I tried to build it 3-4 times, but no luck. And I also tried changing database version but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the version of the DBFlow and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If there any field available like 'isDeleted' of any other boolean variable, Then it's Getter & Setter methods should like this :

Example :

```
boolean isDeleted;

public Boolean isDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
    this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
}
```

Most important is mehtod name like `isDeleted()` &  `setDeleted()`.